# Returning an anonymous tr1 array initialized with boost.assign

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, tr1, assign

Ok, this works on my compiler (vs2008) but I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something non-standard.  Here's a trivial example what I'm doing:

```
std::tr1::array<int, 3> OneTwoThree() {
    return boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3).to_array(std::tr1::array<int, 3>());
}
```

I'm cheating around the fact that the to_array adapter doesn't actually use the argument you pass into it, it's just using it to figure out the type.  The examples, however, show it being used more like this:

```
std::tr1::array<int, 3> a = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3).to_array(a);
```

Any ideas on whether or not just throwing a value-initialized array into to_array it is kosher?  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_...` member functions all take an argument solely for the purpose of assisting with template argument deduction, so yes, passing a value-initialized<sup>†</sup> instance of the same type you want as the return type is safe, though needlessly inefficient.

However, the `to_...` member functions only exist to assist broken compilers that don't properly support templated conversion operators -- why are you using them in the first place? The clean syntax would be simply:

```
boost::array<int, 3> OneTwoThree() {
    return boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3);
}
```

Note that I've used `boost::array<>` here rather than `std::tr1::array<>`; the reason is that the Boost.Assign library has no knowledge (yet) of TR1/C++11 standard libraries, and thus is not properly specialized for `std::array<>` or `std::tr1::array<>`. To add this specialization yourself, and consequently make the above code work with `std::tr1::array<>`, add the following code **after** including the Boost.Assign headers:

```
namespace boost { namespace assign_detail {

template<typename T, std::size_t sz>
type_traits::yes_type assign_is_array(std::tr1::array<T, sz> const*);

}}
```

(Note: only tested with Boost 1.48; earlier versions may need a different specialization.)

---

<sup>†</sup> The syntax in your question is not default-construction, it's value-initialization.

Comment: Right, I was using the to_array member to get around the lack of support for tr1::array.  I'm going to go with the specialization you suggested instead, thanks.  Edited question to say value-initialization.